# On premise file copy from sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, file-shares, windows-server-2019

we have automated powershell scripts wich copy files between folders

```
from:
"\\skdms.xxxxxxx.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\PH"  (library in Sharepoint)
to
"\\10.212.128.67\c$\FC_Data\Faktury_INPUT_SP"   (shared library in network)
```

the script is running from "Task Scheduler" with user sp_farm.

[image]

Everything works fine until someone restarts the server.

After restart (the user sp_farm is not logged in), the library in SHP is not accessible,
the scirpt runs, but throws an error:

```
the folder '\\skdms.xxxxxx.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\PH' is not accessible.
```

Do you know how to set up the scripts to get working after the restart?
(do not have to login to windows server with sp_farm)

Thanks for any advice

Comment: One obvious solution would be to turn your PS Script into a CSOM app, if the sharepoint version is supported, and handle authentication with a different way.
I always faced different kind of problems when trying to access a Mapped Drive to a sharepoint site and i think that these were connected with the WebDAV.
For reference: https://support.intermedia.com/app/articles/detail/a_id/14954/~/sharepoint-webdav-connection-dont-remember-password-after-reboot

Comment: Thanks for advice, 
we solved the problem with another script, wich maps the network drives.

Comment: Great to hear! So the problem was re-authentication after a restart.

Comment: Unfortunetly I can not award your comment, only answers can earn the bounty.

Comment: dont worry, i was happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added an another script wich runs after restart and remaps the network drives:

```
:: Skript slúži na obnovenie mapovania sietových diskov
:: po reštarte servera pre používatela PHOENIX\SkBa1.SP-Farm.
:: Spúšta sa schedulovanou úlohou:
::     „Mapovanie priecinkov pre SkBa1.SP-Farm“

echo ========================                                 >  c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
echo. | date | find "current"                                 >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
echo. | time | find "current"                                 >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
echo Prihlaseny: %username%                                   >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt

echo ========================                                 >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
echo "Net use..."                                             >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
net use \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\PH        >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
net use \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\BE        >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
net use \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\eMailsInc >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
net use \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\dmstest\Mailsinc            >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt

echo ========================                                 >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
echo "Dir..."                                                 >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
Dir \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\PH            >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
Dir \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\BE            >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
Dir \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\DMSTest\HotFolder\eMailsInc     >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
Dir \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\dmstest\Mailsinc                >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
::Dir \\skdms.phoenix.loc\sites\dmstest\MailsincXX            >> c:\_Script\logs\dir_log.txt
::pause
```